# OAuth2 The grant type was not specified

Tags: php, oauth-2.0

I follow this steps, but when execute this:

```
curl -u testclient:testpass http://localhost/token.php -d 'grant_type=client_credentials'
```

receive this

```
{"error":"invalid_request,"error_description":"The grant type was not specified in the request"}
```

How i should put the 'grant_type' in request in this  case

These are two files
server.php

```
$dsn      = 'mysql:dbname=oauth2;host=localhost';
$username = 'root';
$password = '';

// error reporting (this is a demo, after all!)
ini_set('display_errors',1);error_reporting(E_ALL);
require_once('../src/OAuth2/Autoloader.php');
OAuth2\Autoloader::register();

$storage = new OAuth2\Storage\Pdo(array('dsn' => $dsn, 'username' => $username, 'password' => $password));
$server = new OAuth2\Server($storage);
$server->addGrantType(new OAuth2\GrantType\AuthorizationCode($storage)); // or any grant type you like!
```

token.php

```
require_once __DIR__.'/server.php';

// Handle a request for an OAuth2.0 Access Token and send the response to the client
$server->handleTokenRequest(OAuth2\Request::createFromGlobals())->send();
```

Comment: your question is not clear. But try this: `curl -u testclient:testpass -H application/x-www-form-urlencoded http://localhost/token.php -d 'grant_type=client_credentials'`

Comment: Same error and Sorry for my English.

Comment: Not english, you should give more info about `token.php` such as libs used

Comment: the request is technically fine but perhaps `token.php` does not allow (or know about) that grant type

Comment: follow the complete example and use `$server->addGrantType(new OAuth2\GrantType\ClientCredentials($storage));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

curl -u testclient:testpass http://localhost/token.php -d grant_type=client_credentials

Comment: May not be exactly related, but adding comment as someone might find it helpful - **OAuth2 Grant Types:** Authorization Code, Client Credentials, Device Code, Refresh Token. Note that it even can be extended. Ref: https://oauth.net/2/grant-types/

Answer (score 0):

These are two files
server.php

```
$dsn      = 'mysql:dbname=oauth2;host=localhost';
$username = 'root';
$password = '';

// error reporting (this is a demo, after all!)
ini_set('display_errors',1);error_reporting(E_ALL);
require_once('../src/OAuth2/Autoloader.php');
OAuth2\Autoloader::register();

$storage = new OAuth2\Storage\Pdo(array('dsn' => $dsn, 'username' => $username, 'password' => $password));
$server = new OAuth2\Server($storage);
$server->addGrantType(new OAuth2\GrantType\AuthorizationCode($storage)); // or any grant type you like!
```

token.php

```
require_once __DIR__.'/server.php';

// Handle a request for an OAuth2.0 Access Token and send the response to the client
$server->handleTokenRequest(OAuth2\Request::createFromGlobals())->send();
```